# Post link redirects to homepage on first session - Wordpress custom template

Tags: wordpress, redirect, session-cookies, custom-post-type

I'm currently working on and troubleshooting the following custom wordpress site: https://matsomenosgatos.gr/

The issue here I cannot resolve is that, when you click on a post link (for example https://matsomenosgatos.gr/nba-teleionoyn-oi-leikers/)
on first session it redirects you to hompepaga and if you click on it again it gets you to the post as it should.

I've been struggling to fix this for a long time now, but I've never seen a similar issue before.
If anyone has an idea I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks for your time.